# Why had the first humans on earth suffered, if they did not do any bad karma from previous lives?

Tags: karma, rebirth

Karma philosophy teaches that everyone suffer or born according to their past karma or karma of previous birth.

The first humans did not have births earlier. Then what was the karma of first born humans for which they born again, and suffered  during their lifetime.

Comment: there was never a 'first' human.

Comment: What do you mean by first born? Do you mean Manu?

Comment: There’s no such thing as a first birth.  Every soul in Samsara has had infinitely many past births going infinitely far back in time.

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16683/is-there-the-first-birth-of-a-jiva-soul-in-the-material-world-or-not/16685

Comment: first brith depends on phiolosphy you follow basically 3 different belief system are there 1. advaita 2. Vishsta advaita 3. Dvaita, now According to 1,2 They both believe God is the material cause of the universe, God created the universe matter, Lets take as per 2. God became many at one point of time because there is only one existed that is god. all you see matter is god himself.. Then the question of karma comes when it the karma started, Karma started when God created the matter.. For 3. God never created matter he only formed the universe by arrangin the matter.. which already present..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to cyclic nature of time, there is nothing like first birth. Lord Krishna explains this [to Arjuna] in [Gita 2.12](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=2&field_nsutra_value=12&etadi=1&choose=1):

> न त्वेवाहं जातु नासं न त्वं नेमे जनाधिपाः।
>
> न चैव न भविष्यामः सर्वे वयमतः परम्।।2.12।।
>
> There never was a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor any of these kings of men. Nor will there be any time in future when all of us shall cease to be. {English Translation By Swami Adidevananda}

Comment: So, can we say that the number of living beings living on earth remains constant, given the fact that the human population has risen too much. What I can think is that as other animals are dying and becoming extinct at a rapid rate, the soul are maintaining balance by increasing the human population. In that case, it perfectly makes sense.

Comment: And also, what about moksha, in that case, the soul is free of the circle of life, so the number of souls should decrease, So, there must be some point where they are created. I ask these questions not to mock you, but only because I think you are smart enough to have an answer.

Comment: 1. "can we say that the number of living beings living on earth remains constant" -no..they can increase, decrease from another lokas like swarga.. 2. "what about moksha, in that case, the soul is free of the circle of life"- they gets united with the Brahmn but that doesn't mean they had no past history and their souls will loose it's status, it simply mean they won't come in normal birth-death cycle..liberated souls also sometimes come in life cycle for a mission but we call them Avtar or Adhikarika..