# How does God decide who becomes a nityasuri?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, vishishtadvaita, ramanujacharya, samsara, nityasuri

If God is fair and square, why are we **baddhatmas**(Those jivas that are temporarily bound by karma), while some atmas get to become **nityasuris**(These are the members of the Divine Ministering Assembly  ).

What did I do to first get stuck in samsara and suffer?

Comment: God is the neutral atman witness, those who are nityasuris are resonating suras who seeked the creator, while baddhatmas seeked the creation. Ofcourse, whoever gave priority to creation over timeless creator, how can they end up as immortals as creation is time dependent in itself. What your mind did in Maya during previous births is irrelevant for today, hence the nature wipes out memories of old actions with the new birth which have already became your current traits and ambiance, what is God interested in what you will do in the present with the rare human shell.

Comment: The concept of baddhatmas and  nityasuris has no  basis.  Only Sri Vaishnavaites propagate this theory.   According to sages, everyone will get chance to move up in SPIRITUALITY and get liberated.  Pray to God and if possible, please approach a REAL guru for further guidance.  If you are unable to decide, who the REAL guru is, pray to God at your home sincerely and God will show you the way.

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV "The concept of baddhatmas and nityasuris has no basis." - It does have a basis, a Jiva that is trapped in samsara is called a baddhatma, a soul that is liberated is called a muktatma, and a soul that is eternally liberated is called a nityasuri. Hence, if you believe in moksha, which is admitted by all scriptures, then you believe in baddhatmas and muktatmas.

Comment: It is the theory of Sri Vaishnavaites and not applicable to everyone.  They can live with their theories.  @Ikshvaku

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV Do you believe in moksha and samsara, which is admitted by all scriptures? If so, then you believe in baddhatmas and muktatmas.

Comment: I belong to different school of thought.  The ideas of Sri Vaishnavaites emanate from Vishistadvaita and I do adhere to different ideology  with respect of Samsara, liberation, etc.  @Ikshvaku

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV Ok, was just wondering.

Comment: I think the question itself is wrong, no one becomes nitya suri, so they are nitya suris. That is those are the positions not taken by any jivas, I hope you are a visishtadvaita follower. Lakshmi is a nitya suri according to sri vaishnavas , she is also a jivatma( acc to some sri vaishnavas) but she is eternal (so are all jivas) as paramatma. Narayana do not chose them, they are also verily Narayana but subservient to him. Comparing baddhatmas and nitya suris itself is wrong as it is like comparing jivas and paramatma ( though both are same yet different at the same time acc to VA).

Comment: Perceive no differnce between nitya suris and Narayana only exception being that nitya suris are jivas, and subservient to him. According to VA we are all his bodies (yasya atma shariram). And  why are you suffering in samsara?, you wouldn't if you really realize the materialistic things in samsara which causes pain are inferior and seek Narayana as only refugee, there is no fault even if you consider a realized soul as verily narayana. Baddha jivas have papa karmas obstructing them to get the knowledge of Brahman. Additionally I dont think this site is a good place to learn  Visishtadvaita.

Comment: //The concept of baddhatmas and nityasuris has no basis. Only Sri Vaishnavaites propagate this theory.//  If you adhere to different theology then better stop commenting on other theologies and beliefs. You seems to attack vaishnavas and their beliefs in general in a subtle manner, if you don't like them then ignore them instead of making bitter comments. If I am correct you adhere to Ramakrishna paramahamsa and of course pro-shakta leanings, kindly refrain from attack/hurting others believes in a public forum, better create a blog for yourself and share your knownledge. @Srimannnarayana K V.

Comment: You can tender your advice  **kindly refrain from attack/hurting others believes in a public forum, better create a blog for yourself and share your knowledge**, to Sri Vaishnava fanatic members of this site.  They have been resorting to soft proselytising of Sri Vaishnava theories since long in this site.  Those **Sri Vaishnava fanatic members** have been intimidating other members @Satya

Comment: I think you are not following the META posts of this site.  You can go back and check those META posts to understand as to who started calling Sri Ramakrishna, Swami Vivekananda,etc, as Neo-vedantin.  You can also advise **Sri Vaishnava fanatic members**, to Stop calling others **troll**.  And, finally ask **your biased moderator** to remain  neutral, being a moderator.  Then everything will fall in line @Satya

Comment: There is a Rig Vedic mantra **tad viṣṇoḥ paramaṃ padaṃ sadā paśyanti sūrayaḥ |
divīva cakṣurātatam ||** (RV I.22.20).  The words **sadā paśyanti sūrayaḥ** in the mantra was wrongly interpreted by Sri Ramanuja, suiting to his theory of **nitya suri**.  The Rig Vedic mantra has a different meaning. @strugglingseeker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113105/discussion-between-satya-and-srimannarayana-k-v).

Comment: I'm not expert in Sri Vaishnavism, but I think no one can become a nitya suri. One either is a nitya suri or he is not a nitya suri, but it's impossible to become a nitya suri. The nitya suris are souls eternally liberated in Vaikuntha, the eternal kingdom of God, ie eternal abode of Lord Vishnu, namely those souls has never experienced samsara or repeated births and deaths in this material world of misery because they have never came or fall from Vaikuntha to this world of misery and samsara. Or that is to say those souls have lived since infinite past in Vaikuntha and they still live there.

Comment: Related: Is there the first birth of a jiva soul in the material world or not? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16683/2790

Comment: @satya will I be able to discuss the topic with you in chat? Adiyen

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is given in the Gita. God is looking for devotion.

> I am the same towards all beings. None is hateful, and none, dear to
> Me. **But those who worship Me with devotion dwell in Me, and I too
> dwell in them.**

Gita 9.29

It would take a sage to answer the second question.

Comment: if you follow some philosophy which is hypocritical in itself than it requires pseudo sages to give an acceptable answer which may not be acceptable at all.. Every jivaatma has Jivaswarroop and swabha accompained..the body of jiva is made in  the ratio of light =x, (space and vayu) = y and (water and earth) =z in 8 parts for example for devas sushma deha is composed of 4/8x, 3/8y and 1/8z for gandharvas 3/8x,2/8y and 2/8z for humans 1/8x, 3/8y and 4/8z since Jiva existed before creation along with all the material universe in sushma form. based on the this ratio

Comment: godly being are created by their own nature according to jiva swabhava

Comment: Best analogy is Gardener sowing different seeds in his field for  growing different variety of plants, trees and other creeper.. it depends on the seed not the gardener why one is mongo tree why other is cocunut means it depends the seeed he planted not himself he watered the same amount of water to all the seed but based on nature of seed trees grow

Comment: @PrasannaR plz write an answer with references.

Comment: @idolworshipper im not an expert in scriptures whatever i have given here is what Great scholar like Bannaje Govindacharya told while giving details about srimad bhagavatam.. but i know this is true...that is why shared but for answers all the reference are needed which i dont have..