# What is the beginning of anadi karma?

Tags: vedanta, karma, sri-vaishnava, moksha, jiva

It is said that we are in samsara due to anadi karma.

If anadi karma has an end, i.e. moksha, that means that is has to have a beginning too.

What was the first incident that put jiva in samsara? What was the first ever karma?

Comment: Related: Is there the first birth of a jiva soul in the material world or not? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16683/2790

Answer (score 1):

> If anadi karma has an end, i.e. moksha, that means
> that is has to have a beginning too.

The attribute anadi-tva means the quality of not having a 'beginning'.

For something to not have an 'end' the attribute is an-anta-tva.

It is perfectly possible for something to not have a beginning but have an end.

---

As far as 'first karma' is concerned, there is no such thing.

Jivas are in 'baddha' state (due to karma association) for all time in the past.

This may not make sense but that is a separate issue. This is what Vedanta says.

This is not stated directly but inferred from the sutra that says that the Lord cannot be accused of partiality or cruelty. (If the jIva was karma-free at some point of time and eventually acquired karma, and given karma drives the differences seen in society, the Lord could be blamed of partiality/cruelty).

Source: prayojanatvAdhikaraNa of the Brahmasutras.