# When one achieves Moksha, will loved ones ever be reunited?

Tags: moksha

The thought of never seeing my husband again really is devastating to me. I am new to all of this and learning for the first time.

Comment: That is a very important question. This is same question which Arjun asked Krishna. Gita will you help in finding the right answer.

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43719/what-happens-to-a-liberated-soul?rq=1

Comment: Namaste. Firstly it depends on whether the person attains moksha or not. There are different Lokas above the earth (6 of them from Bhuvarloka to Satyaloka). It depends in which Loka the person has gone. Many scriptures talk of the fact that a lady reunites with her husband in whichever Loka he is. Then comes moksha which is beyond the Lokas, the parama Padam of God. By focusing ones mind to god, the source of infinite compassion, a person can achieve his grace, ask him for both husband and wife, why not? Also many a times peoples relatives come to take them when their time on earth is over.

Comment: Thank you all very very much. I’m very grateful for your insight and thoughtfulness.