# What is the concept of Moksha in Advaita Vedanta?

Tags: moksha

Advaita Vedanta holds that all of us have the same self.
Then what is the concept of Moksha in Advaita Vedant ?
Do people still take birth [after getting Moksha?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43730/23709)

Comment: Mokṣa by definition means freedom from the cycle of death and rebirth. Also, please don't use stack exchange like google/quora/reddit. This is a dedicated question-answer site, where you ask a question only when you have done some decent amount of work and deliberation in it, and still face a doubt.  You are a not a new member and also have 1000+ reputation, we would expect you to know the purpose of this site. This question is basically, if you have studied Advaita vedānta is too generic, and that only requires basic study.

Comment: @Bingming I Know Moksha means freedom from cycle and rebirth. But in Hinduism , there are too many philosophies. And many are contradictory. Dvaita Philosphy also exists , which is opposite to Advaita Vedant.
In Advait vedant  if all of us have the same self , how can a person get free from cycle of birth and death. Also Vishnu himself keeps taking birth , so even he is not free from birth and death cycle.  So, It is not as easy as you think it to be.

Comment: I know mokṣa is different in various Ind phls. But in all traditions, mokṣa specificially means freedom from rebirth including Advaita.  Probably you should include some part of this comment in the question, that would make a better question because it still lacks specificity. Also in Dvaita, Viṣṇu is supreme btw, and is not in saṁsāra, so that is incorrect what you said. In Advaita, on the other hand, Viṣṇu is just in the category of Īśvara, so subject to Māyā and not ultimate reality, such as Brahman. I never said it's easy or difficult.

Comment: Also, this view of same Self is too vague, that's not how it is actually in Advaita, Advaita doesn't stress on bare unity, that's not the approach, it dismisses duality but doesn't affirm unity.

Comment: @Bingming Advait just talks about knowing the true nature of reality. Birth and death many occur but you know the true natue of reality that - "You are unborn". I think in Advait you are just free from suffering, but not birth or death . Just like Vishnu takes birth but is free from sufferings.

Comment: Well, that's wrong. That's your personal view, not Advaita. Advaita is not only knowing the true nature of reality but much more than that. Viṣṇu is Īśvara, and Īśvara is projection of Brahman on the plane of Māyā. That is why it is subject to karma and isn't ultimate reality.

Comment: through brahmajñāna one attain mokṣa and becomes a jīvanmukta forever freeing themselves of the cycles of life and death. That's how it is in Advaita.

Comment: @Bingming This is not my personal view, read the link i have given in the question . Yudhistira talks about Moksha means just having true knowledge.

Comment: Well, I am talking about Śaṅkara's advaita not Yudhiṣṭhira's description of Mokṣa.

Comment: Your question is asking about the stance of Advaita.
Yudhiṣṭhira is not the authority on Advaita. The first authorities are Gauḍapāda and Śaṅkarācārya in the Advaita tradition.

Comment: @Bingming Not taking birth again is illogical because it creates a [problem of infinite regression.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2457/is-moksha-a-permanent-state/10744#10744) . Life is cyclical , you would have to live this again when this universe is created again. You may live in Moksha only until this universe ends but when this universe is created again , you will have to live this life again.

Comment: well, it's not illogical in Advaita tradition to come out of the cycle of life and death. Because this notion of cyclicity is itself is due to avidyā and isn't the true reality.

Comment: @Bingming Only Scriptures having words of Gods in it are authority. Also I don't believe in authority of anyone . Unless something doesn't make logical sense , how can I believe it , doesn't make any sense to me.  Universe is cyclical , and this universe will be created again , and you will be living this life again and reading this comment again , that is for 100 percent sure by logic.

Comment: Again , this is your personal view, you didn't support this by śruti, nor is it so in Advaita. In Advaita, the notion of life and death, creation and destruction are part of saṁsāra. The only ultimate and permanent reality is Brahman. And Brahman doesn't die nor is it created.

Comment: @Bingming But we have taken infinite births and we haven't got Moksha then by probabily, even chance of getting moksha in future is also zero.

Answer (score 2):

Moksha is freedom from the endless transmigration cycle. Here are some passages explaining moksha as understood in Advaita Vedanta school.

**Perfect Yoga**

> When men of knowledge, conversant with the rules of Yoga, become as
> fixed as a stake of wood, and as immovable as a mountain, then are
> they said to be in Yoga. When one does not hear, and smell, and taste,
> and see; when one is not conscious of any touch; when one’s mind
> becomes perfectly free from every purpose; when one is not conscious
> of anything, when one cherishes no thought; when one becomes like a
> piece of wood, then is one called by the wise to be in perfect Yoga.
> At such a time one shines like a lamp that burns in a place where
> there is no wind; at such a time one becomes freed even from one’s
> subtle form, and perfectly united with Brahma. When one attains to
> such progress, one has no longer to ascend or to fall among
> intermediate beings. When persons like ourselves say that there has
> been a complete identification of the Knower, the Known, and
> Knowledge, then is the Yogin said to behold the Supreme Soul.

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCCVII**

**Yudhisthira** **on Emancipation**

> There are two well-known paths (for us), viz, the path of the Pitris
> and the path of the gods. They that perform sacrifices go by the
> Pitri-path, while they that are for salvation, go by the god-path. By
> penances, by Brahmacharya, by study (of the Vedas), the great Rishis,
> casting off their bodies, proceed to regions that are above the power
> of death. Worldly enjoyments have been styled as bonds. They have also
> been called action. Liberated from these two sins (viz, bonds and
> action) one attains to the highest end. ….As a person on the hill-top
> looketh down upon men on the plain below, so he that has got up on the
> top of the mansion of knowledge, seeth people grieving for things that
> do not call for grief. He, however, that is of foolish understanding,
> does not see this. He who, casting his eyes on visible things, really
> seeth them, is said to have eyes and understanding. The faculty called
> understanding is so called because of the knowledge and comprehension
> it gives of unknown and incomprehensible things. He who is acquainted
> with the words of persons that are learned, that are of cleansed
> souls, and that have attained to a state of Brahma, succeeds in
> obtaining great honours. When one seeth creatures of infinite
> diversity to be all one and the same to be but diversified emanations
> from the same essence, one is then said to have attained Brahma. Those
> who reach this high state of culture attain to that supreme and
> blissful end, and not they who are without knowledge, or they who are
> of little and narrow souls, or they who are bereft of understanding,
> or they who are without penances. Indeed, everything rests on the
> (cultivated) understanding!’

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section XVII**

**Bhisma/Suka on emancipation**

> Bhishma continued [Suka said],’..By knowledge, one attains to that
> whither there is no occasion for grief; whither one becomes freed from
> birth and death; whither one is not subject to decrepitude; whither
> one transcends the state of conscious existence; whither is Brahma
> which is Supreme, Unmanifest, immutable, ever-existent, imperceptible,
> above the reach of pain, immortal, and transcending destruction;
> whither all become freed from the influence of all pairs of opposites
> (like pleasure and pain, etc), as also wish or purpose. Reaching that
> stage, they cast equal eyes on everything, becoming universal friends
> and devoted to the good of all the creatures.’

**Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCXLI**